# Issues with NifTI images under Mathematica (Neurotica package)

Tags: import

I have some troubles when I want to import NifTI files with Mathematica. When I do:

```
Import["Brats18_CBICA_AAB_1/Brats18_CBICA_AAB_1_flair.nii.gz", {"GZIP", "NifTI"}];
```

It returns me an error:

[image]

Did someone got this error? Is there a way to solve this problem?

What is strange is that it works well with the 30 first images of my folder of 285 brains ...

Thanks for your help, N.B.

Comment: Hm. Neurotica is neither one of the standard packages nor one that is discussed here often. Also, NifTI is not one of the supported `$ImportFormats`. Instead, the import filter is defined [here](https://github.com/noahbenson/Neurotica/blob/master/src/Neurotica/NifTI.m) Maybe it is a good idea to contact the authors of the package directly? Certainly, they will want to have the problematic file in order to reproduce the error.

Comment: I am not sure that Neurotica is still maintained. I would try this package: https://github.com/mfroeling/QMRITools

Comment: Thank you a lot ! QMRITools works fine !! :) @Szabolcs

Comment: What about BioFormatsLink, as suggested below? I'd be curious if it works well.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram officially maintains a package called BioFormatsLink which has NifTI support. I recommend you try this:

https://github.com/WolframResearch/BioFormatsLink

Comment: I find BioFormatsLink in Mathematica 12.0.0.0 but I do not find anything related to Nifti in this package.

Comment: It is listed here: https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.9.0/supported-formats.html. To use it after loading, `Import["path/to/file.nii", "BioFormats"] `